# What is the viscosity of Sun surface?

Tags: sun, plasma-physics, kinetic-theory, viscosity

It should be possible to compute value from hydrodynamics of Solar prominence. What is the current estimate of Solar surface viscosity?

Comment: Please be more precise. What do you mean by "surface"?

Comment: This is an astrophysics question, not a physics question; it would be better asked on http://astronomy.stackexchange.com .

Comment: Yes, I am asking about the surface of photosphere.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> What is the viscosity of Sun surface?

By "solar surface" I am going to assume you mean the [photosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosphere).  In that case, then the question is whether you are asking about *dynamic* ($\mu$) or *kinematic* ($\nu$) [viscosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity).

According to a paper by [*Cowley* [1990]](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1990ApJ...348..328C), the relevant parameters for the photospheric surface are: T ~ 4700 K, $\rho$ ~ 4.9 x 10<sup>-9</sup> g/cm<sup>3</sup>, and n<sub>e</sub> ~ 1.1 x 10<sup>11</sup> cm<sup>3</sup>.

We know that the following is an okay approximation $\mu \propto \rho \ \lambda \ V_{T}$, where $\lambda$ is the [mean free path](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_free_path) and $V_{T}$ is the [thermal speed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/179057/59023).  One can approximate $\lambda \propto (n_{e} \ \sigma)^{-1}$, where $\sigma$ is the collisional cross-section (here [Coulomb collisions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb_collision)).

From Table 2 in *Cowley* [1990], we find that $\mu$ ~ 4.1 x 10<sup>-4</sup> g cm<sup>-1</sup> s<sup>-1</sup> and since we know $\rho$ we can see that $\nu$ = $\mu/\rho$ ~ 8.4 x 10<sup>4</sup> cm<sup>2</sup> s<sup>-1</sup>.

> What is the current estimate of Solar surface viscosity?

I imagine things have not changed much other than more accurate density and temperature constraints for various regions.  However, any model that attempts to make things more accurate will quickly become nearly impossible without simulations (e.g., adding multiple ion species with energy-dependent cross-sections is not a trivial task when they have different temperatures and densities).

Comment: "ρ ~ 4.9 x 10^-9 kG/L " Didn't realize that photosphere is so thin. Seems like ideal gas would give good approximation. Thank you.

Comment: @Stepan - To be fair to the photosphere, it gets denser as one goes deeper rather quickly (i.e., exponentially).  ;)