# How does Viscosity of the Sun varies as we go from core to the convective zone?

Tags: thermodynamics, astrophysics, astronomy, sun, viscosity

How does Viscosity of the Sun varies with its radius? [image]

For. eg, Here is the graph of the Density of the sun v/s radius. I am looking for the Viscosity v/s radius plot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/363413/59023