# How to estimate the Kolmogorov scale of the plasma in solar corona?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, astrophysics, sun, turbulence

I would like to estimate the order of Kolmogorov scale
$$
l_k = \left( \frac{\nu^3}{\epsilon_d}\right)^{1/4}
$$
of the plasma in solar corona, so I need to determine the viscosity $\nu$ and dissipation rate $\epsilon_d$ first.

I have read references and I found the viscosity can be estimate by assuming the Maxwellian distribution of the plasma electrons, which gives
$$
\nu \sim (k_B T / n_e)^{1/2}.
$$

However, I haven't found ways to estimate the dissipation rate $\epsilon_d$, which may be accessed by dimensional analysis: $v^3/L$, but it is hard to determine these parameters.

Comment: Related:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/363269/59023