# Alfven velocity in space. Maybe too large?

Tags: plasma-physics, solar-wind, magnetohydrodynamics

I'm calculating the Alfven velocity in space plasma.

`B = 4.2 nT (nanoTesla)`

`mu_0 = 1.25663706212e-06 (vacuum permeability in Henry per meter)`

`n = 21.8906  (number density in 1/cm^3)`

`m_p = 1.67262192369e-27 (proton mass in kg)`

The Alfven velocity equation is:

```
V_A = B/sqrt(mu_0*n*m_p)
```

I calculated it as

```
V_A = (4.2*1e-9)/sqrt(mu_0*n*1e-6*mp)
```

here obviously, `4.2*1e-9` for changing from nanoTesla to Tesla and `n*1e-6` for 1/cm^3 to 1/m^3

The result is `18741529400.533485 m/s` or `18741529.400533486 km/s`

Which is too fast, even faster than the speed of light, which is 3*10^8 m/s.

So, am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Your conversion from cm$^{-3}$ to m$^{-3}$ is incorrect, it should be $10^6$ instead

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: $\textrm{cm}^{-3} = (10^{-2} \textrm{m})^{-3} = 10^{6} \textrm{m}^{-3}$

Comment: Oh, you're right. Thank you very much. Too dumb to realize this, hehe.

Comment: Note that $v_A$ is derived in a non-relativistic system, so that it blows up for certain values of $B$, $n$, etc should give pause, as in your case, to double check the math.

Comment: Does this help?  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/179057/59023

Comment: The approximation goes as $V_{A}$ ~ 21.81 B[nT]/$\sqrt{n \[ cm^{-3} \]}$ km/s, where the units in []'s are meant to imply the input units for the magnetic field, B, and the number density, n.  So for your input values I get something like 19.58 km/s.  Side note:  No particle instrument in space is accurate to better than ~5-10%, so reporting more than one decimal place is not necessary.